# Directional Forecast

Tags: forecasting

I've some demand data, for which I wish to judge what will be the direction in the forecast period (Up/Down). What will be a best ML method to do this? Currently I'm using the data given below -

9/4/2016    241
9/11/2016   233
9/18/2016   226
9/25/2016   282
10/2/2016   291
10/9/2016   282
10/16/2016  308
10/23/2016  291
10/30/2016  268
11/6/2016   262
11/13/2016  273
11/20/2016  262
11/27/2016  309
12/4/2016   317
12/11/2016  331
12/18/2016  382
12/25/2016  358
1/1/2017    359
1/8/2017    342
1/15/2017   332
1/22/2017   324
1/29/2017   298
2/5/2017    283
2/12/2017   274
2/19/2017   278
2/26/2017   245
3/5/2017    214
3/12/2017   217
3/19/2017   204
4/16/2017   204
4/23/2017   187
4/30/2017   203
5/7/2017    198
5/14/2017   211
5/21/2017   186
5/28/2017   176
6/4/2017    183
6/11/2017   180
6/18/2017   177
6/25/2017   157
7/2/2017    179
7/9/2017    191

I'm using 'forecastHybrid' package in R with the following code, but unfortunately the forecasts I'm getting based on last observation only (i.e. 191), which doesn't seem to be correct.

Will any other model be relevant here, i.e. SVM, RF etc. Any specific guidance/code in R will be much appreciated.

`mod1 <- hybridModel(t)
fc1 <- forecast(mod1)
fc1`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is DOWN based upon the equation [image]

I don't write r code ....

[image]

EDITED AFTER OP'S COMMENT:

When dealing with a single time series there are a number of possible features/elements/items of a useful model. AUTOBOX a piece of software that I have helped to develop pursues a broad strategy of item selection. First and primary is should memory be used OR should dummy predictors ( level shifts , time trends , seasonal pulses , other time-oriented fixed effects )be used OR should thee be some combination. Secondly are their any anomalies/pulses that need to be treated/adjusted ? Thirdly is there evidence of non-constant error variance and if so should we transform the data OR use weighted least squares to render the model error variance to be homogeneous ALL while validating the assumption that parameters have not varied over time.

Upon running heuristics/model diagnostics in an Exploratory Data Manner , the program iteratively assesses significance by optimizing the sequence of approaches culminating in a possible useful model. The model can be "understood" by examining the ultimate design matrix which was ferreted out by the diagnostics. Here it is .[image] .

The model suggests two time trends 1-18 and 19-38 both clearly visually visually supportable.
The model suggests a level shift i.e. an intercept change at or about period 26
The model suggests an unusual value/pulse at period 16
The model suggests less randomness in the residuals at or about period 17

The freely available parametric software in R does not pursue sufficient global strategies i.e. testing for possible non-gaussian violations and providing remedies often ( nearly always in my biased opinion !) mis-analyzes data. 1 Corinthians 13:11 has words to this effect. If you search in my previous postings on se you will get further examples of results like this.

The human eye is often a great modelling tool and the question is can software proxy the clear eye in identifying meaningful structure. In this case I would have to say a definite yes. Ad hoc approaches as suggested by others in an attempt to do feature engineering is time-wasting and largely unproductive. This is not to say that holiday effects and other calendar effects should not be used . They should ! See my most recent post for an example of that [ARIMA model has trouble forecasting next month](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/297132/arima-model-has-trouble-forecasting-next-month/297192#297192) . Other posts illuminate how holiday effects can be automatically formed and you might also look at  http://www.autobox.com/cms/index.php/afs-university/intro-to-forecasting/doc_download/53-capabilities-presentation .. slide 49-68 .

Comment: Many thanks, but apologies, can you please explain the above model, I mean how do you arrive? Which software and which model has been used in this? If you can please elaborate, I'll be really grateful and hence can proceed accordingly.

Comment: It has been a while . Do you still have questions ?

Answer (score 1):

Well there are several approaches to this:

You could use the data as is and simply try different time series models as you already did. You could also try a random forest or gradient bossted trees but I think the number of observations is to low for them to produce good results.Still, whether a method works well or not can only be answered empirically. Thus, just go for it ( I would recommend to use the caret package)

Another approach would be to change the target variables and to generate a dummy indicating whether demand increased or decreased. You can again use any model that can handle a binary target variable (regression/logistic regression/tree based method/naive bayes and so on)

Moreover, I would suggest that you should spend some time on feature engeneering. You can easily add holidays...time before/after holidays and so on. You can use any expert knowledge or simply common sense to come with new features.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Many thanks for your help and guidance. Can you please shed some light on feature engineering? I was trying an SVM model changing the target variable as - whether the demand is up or down, but that's also giving some errors while fitting SVM. Little more on this will be of great help. Apologies for asking again as I'm a newbie to Machine learning and on the path of learning.

Comment: Sure. I would start easy and not go into svm's just yet. Use a simple OLS and try some new features. If you use svm you need to standardize the data first. Well the first and easy feature is to generate a holiday dummy. A variable that takes the value of one if a given date was holiday and zero otherwise. Christmas is very special in the case of demand. People are shopping heavily before christmas hence you could generate a metric variable that simply counts the days untill christmas from a given start date..lets say starting in November.

Comment: Then I would generate a Dummy indicating the first 2 Weeks after Christmas because generally this is period with low demand. I dont know your specific usecase but maybe you have some info on special marketing events and stuff like that which you could also encode using a dummy. Another important feature might be the weather so you would need to get some weather data predictions. Of course you need use your target variable lagged by x periods if you dont rely on auto time series models.

Comment: with respect to SVM: Use a linear kernel first before going nonlinear. You need to rescale your  features to be on the same scale using a mean/std dev scaler or a min/max scaler. Just search for standardizing features. All this can be done in caret quite easily. If you want help on specific error massanges...well you would need to tell me the exact errormassage :)